# how to run method in parallel in jenkins groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have jenkins shared library which contains internal method (let's call it A())

Currently the A() method run sequentially between 10-100 times.

I want to run A() in parallel with pre define bulk number (10)

I didn't find a way to implement it via groovy, some of the method Jenkins require approval.

What is the way to do it via groovy ( not parallel steps of jenkis) without require any jenkins approval?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you need permissions for this, but just try it:

```
def A = {
    println "hello from A($it)"
    Thread.sleep(Math.random() * 2000 as long)
    println "hello from A($it)"
}

def threads = (0..5).collect { counter ->
    Thread.start { A(counter) }
}

threads.each { it.join() }
```

I put some `println` and some sleep to demonstrate the methods run in parallel. You can replace the body of `A{}` as you wish.

Comment: I tried it, the jenkins job finished successfully but it doesn't print anything in console output.

Comment: Try echo instead of println.

Comment: I did it in the first time print/echo the same - nothing in console output